# Change MariaDB 10.0.17 (MySQL) master to a slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have a MySQL master/slave configuration

```
 --------        --------  
| master |  ->  | slave1 |
 --------        --------
```

I want to kill my current master, transform slave1 to be the new master and have another slave pointing to slave1

```
 --------          ------------        --------
| master |        | new master |  ->  | slave2 |
 --------          ------------        --------
  KILLED
```

What is the best way to do this without database downtime?
I am using MariaDB 10.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your basic process is quite straight forward.

1) Ensure that slave1 has got `log-bin` and `log-slave-updates` enabled (this will require a restart if not)

2) Take a copy of Slave1 and set up Slave2 as a slave of Slave1. You now have 
`Master -> Slave1 -> Slave2`

3) Once you are happy that Slave2 is performing as expected, `set GLOBAL READ_ONLY=on` on the master, and move all your writes to the Slave1.

4) Once this has completed, Shut down the master.

The only downtime you would have would be restarting Slave1 if required, and the time it takes to move your writes from the Master to the Slave1. This part is entirely dependent on your situation.

Comment: Can I follow the steps 1 to 6 of this page (http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html) to the Slave1 copy?

Comment: Yes, that's as good a way as any (of course where that page talks about the `Master` you would be looking at your `Slave1`).